# How can I get working motion keys with `emacs -nw`?

Tags: key-bindings, motion, term

when I start Emacs without windowing system (`-nw`), the motion keys are not working. Instead, I get (parts of) the escape sequences, like:

```
;; This buffer is for text that is not saved, and for Lisp evaluation.    
;; To create a file, visit it with C-o and enter text in its buffer.

[C[B[D[A[A[C[B[D[4~[C][B][A][A]
```

Thats four cursor keys, some function keys, home, end...

Edit:
I see this on my debian buster machine as well as in termux on android. Both share the same configuration.
Running emacs like `emacs -nw -Q` gets rid of the problem…

Comment: What terminal are you using and what's the value of `$TERM` inside of it?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10: I'm using the plain console (no GUI/X11 installed), $TERM is linux
I tried it with an RXVT, TERM=rxvt-unicode-256color : the same
With xterm: TERM=xterm: almost the same, just no square brackets.
With termux on android: TERM=xterm-256color : the same ...

Comment: What distro and keymap are you using? Does the problem persist with no site files (`emacs -Q`)?

Comment: @DoMiNeLa10: I'm using debian buster and termux on android. With `emacs -nw -Q` the motion keys work fine in both setups! Seems I have to figure out what's wrong in the configuration...

Comment: If you find out that your problem isn't related to your init file, the problem might be related to site files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my own keymap definition:

```
(global-set-key '[(meta \[)]               'mg-match-paren)
```

Re-defining that fixed my problem.